# Can I conclude $f$ is holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that for a fixed $w\in D(0,1)$, the function
> $$F(z)=\dfrac{w-z}{1-\overline{w}z}\quad\forall z\in D(0,1)$$ is holomorphic.

My attempt:
Since $|\overline{w}z|<1$, we have $1-\overline{w}z\neq 0$. Because if it was, then $|\overline{w}z|=1$ (Contradiction!)
Can I conclude that $F$ is holomorphic here?

Comment: What is the domain of $F$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I edited, thanks!

Comment: If you can show that F(z) is complex differentiable, then you have shown it is holomorphic (on its domain, which has not been specified in the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you wrote, all that you can deduce is that the definition of $F$ makes sense (which is something you should not have to prove, since otherwise the problem would make no sense).

You can use the fact that the functions $z\mapsto wz$ and $z\mapsto1-\overline wz$ are holomorphic, together with the fact that the quotient of two holomorphic functions is holomorphic.